# SSRS report not being deployed onto the report server

Tags: reporting-services

I am having a problem with deploying the SSRS report onto the report server. When I try to deploy the report from visual studio, I get the following error:

> The permissions granted to user `'krishna'` are insufficient for performing this operation.

I am not sure where to give the permissions so that the report gets deployed and I can see my reports on the reports folder.

Comment: Pretty basic, but don't forget to [actually install a SQL reporting server on your machine](https://mssqltrek.com/2012/02/10/installingadding-featuressrs-to-an-existing-sql-installation/)

Answer (score 4):

According to the article [How to fix Reporting Services permissions are insufficient for performing operation (rsAccessDenied)](http://www.gotknowhow.com/articles/reportserver-permissions-granted-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation-rsaccessdenied):

> 1. Make sure you have access configured to the URL **`http://localhost/reports`** using the SQL Reporting Services Configuration. To do this:
>
>    1. Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager -> then connect to the report server instance  -> then click on Report Manager URL.
>    2. In the Report Manager URL page, click the Advanced button -> then in the Multiple Identities for Report Manager, click Add.
>    3. In the Add a Report Manager HTTP URL popup box, select Host Header and type in: localhost
>    4. Click OK to save your changes.
> 2. Now start/ run Internet Explorer using **Run as Administrator**.
>
>    - **NOTE**: If you don't see the 'Site Settings' link in the top left corner while at **`http://localhost/reports`** it is probably because you aren't running IE as an Administrator or you haven't assigned your computer's 'domain\username' to the reporting services roles, see how to do this in the next few steps.
> 3. Then go to: **`http://localhost/reports`**   (you may have to login with your Computer's username and password)
> 4. You should now be directed to the Home page of SQL Server Reporting Services here: **`http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx`**
> 5. From the Home page, click the **Properties** tab, then click New Role Assignment
> 6. In the Group or user name textbox, add the 'domain\username' which was in the error message
>
>    - *(in my case, I added: DOUGDELL3-PC\DOUGDELL3 for the 'domain\username', in your case you can find the domain\username for your computer in the rsAccessDenied error message).
> 7. Now check all the checkboxes; Browser, Content Manager, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder, and then click OK.
> 8. Your domain\username should now be assigned to the Roles that will give you access to deploy your reports to the Report Server.  If you're using Visual Studio or SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio to deploy your reports to your local reports server, you should now be able to.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue, but the resolution was different.
looking at `http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` and I had to 'edit item security' to get the parent permissions to apply to the child folders and items (reports).

When I manually tried to upload using the "Upload File" function, it became clear.
(! Replacing an item with another one that has the same name, but is a different type, is not allowed.)

It seems the folders where the report is stored did not allow overwriting. I applied the parent folder permissions over the reports folder and we were able to deploy using Visual Studio again.  Not sure how it got into this state.